# google Closure Compiler reports: JSC_TRAILING_COMMA

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure

Im using google Closure Compiler to compress my js, anyhow I get the following error message:

JSC_TRAILING_COMMA: Parse error. Internet Explorer has a non-standard intepretation of trailing commas. Arrays will have the wrong length and objects will not parse at all. at line 8698 character 5 in post-login.js
                ];

The error is in the first line of this code, but I could not figure out whats wrong with it...

```
var plot = $.jqplot('usst_points_last_10_days', [data], {
    title: '<h3 class="startGrafHeadline">' + global_language['discriptive']['usst']['visits_in_detail'] + '</h3>',
    seriesColors: ["#00FF00"], 
    series: [{renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer}],
    axesDefaults: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
        tickOptions: {
            angle: -30,
            fontSize: '10pt'
        }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact code you are compiling? You sample does not produce that warning for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the line just before the line that the compiler is complaining about.  This will be the last line is some other file, perhaps.

If you examine your command line or build script, that will lead you to the answer.  It seems likely that you are compiling multiple files or are pre-concatenating many files before compilation.  What closure compiler is telling you is to look at line 8698.

If you have some logical explanation about why you think the error is contained in this code, please let us know your reasoning.

If you post more information, I may be able to improve this answer.

There is a handy tool for using closure-compiler through a web UI that may help you convince yourself that you have not found the offending line:

http://closure-compiler.appspot.com